# Animate-it clashing with Materalize Date-Picker

Tags: html, forms, animation, datepicker, materialize

There's a weird issue that I had popped into a few days ago, but still cannot find a suitable solution as to how best to go about fixing it. I am currently creating a website where-in I need a certain date-picker to be used (Materalize Date-Picker).

https://codepen.io/Shadow1209/pen/oWvxav

```
//HTML
<div class="col-md-5 horizontal">
   <div class="">
     <form class="contact-form form">
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend">Some Form</legend>
            <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" class="textbox">
            <input type="text" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname" class="textbox surname">
            <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" class="textbox">
            <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone Number" class="textbox phone">
            <input type="date" name="Start Date" placeholder="Start Date" class="textbox datepicker">
            <input type="date" name="End Date" placeholder="End Date" class="textbox datepicker">
            <textarea name="Enquiry" placeholder="Enquiry" class="textbox textarea"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="form-button">Some Button</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="  col-md-5 horizontal">
   <div class=" ">
     <form class="contact-form form">
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend">Some Form</legend>
            <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" class="textbox">
            <input type="text" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname" class="textbox surname">
            <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" class="textbox">
            <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone Number" class="textbox phone">
            <input type="date" name="Start Date" placeholder="Start Date" class="textbox datepicker">
            <input type="date" name="End Date" placeholder="End Date" class="textbox datepicker">
            <textarea name="Enquiry" placeholder="Enquiry" class="textbox textarea"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="form-button">Some Button</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

//CSS
    .horizontal
    {
      display:inline-block;
    }

//JS

.horizontal
{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

There you can find an example of code that I just quickly arranged to display the "normal" way that the date-picker is supposed to work; basically once the start-date or end-date is clicked on, the pop-up takes over the viewport and centers itself there.

However, once I added animations to the project by means of Animate-it in order to include scrolling animations, issues arose, where the date-picker would suddenly no longer cover the viewport, but rather just the section (form) itself, as can be seen here:

(To add animations, I added the animatedParent and animateOnce classes to the outer container, and the animated fadeInDown classes to the inner containers, as described by the code-creator)

https://codepen.io/Shadow1209/pen/QvLEEB

```
<div class="animatedParent animateOnce col-md-5 horizontal">
   <div class="animated fadeInDown">
     <form class="contact-form form">
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend">Some Form</legend>
            <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" class="textbox">
            <input type="text" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname" class="textbox surname">
            <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" class="textbox">
            <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone Number" class="textbox phone">
            <input type="date" name="Start Date" placeholder="Start Date" class="textbox datepicker">
            <input type="date" name="End Date" placeholder="End Date" class="textbox datepicker">
            <textarea name="Enquiry" placeholder="Enquiry" class="textbox textarea"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="form-button">Some Button</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="animatedParent animateOnce col-md-5 horizontal">
   <div class="animated fadeInDown">
     <form class="contact-form form">
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend">Some Form</legend>
            <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" class="textbox">
            <input type="text" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname" class="textbox surname">
            <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" class="textbox">
            <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone Number" class="textbox phone">
            <input type="date" name="Start Date" placeholder="Start Date" class="textbox datepicker">
            <input type="date" name="End Date" placeholder="End Date" class="textbox datepicker">
            <textarea name="Enquiry" placeholder="Enquiry" class="textbox textarea"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="form-button">Some Button</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have even tried changing from Animate-It to Wow Animations, but the problem stayed the same.

While investigating the code, I found out that, should I remove the classes 'animated', 'fadeInDown', and the newly automatically added 'go' class, the issue goes away. This in turn made me think that maybe a way to work around the issue would be to create an on click event that removes the classes from the parent container once a date-selector field has been clicked on, however this does not really seem like a solution to the issue and more of a work-around.

My question would be, "Is there a good way to go about fixing the issue rather than having to resort to creating a work-around?"

Thank you for any help.